# Curl command is automatically altering the hostname

Tags: linux, curl

I am running the curl command as shown below:

```
curl "http://localhost/dir/"
```

The version of curl installed on our system is 7.19.0. Curl is converting this URL into the following, which is strange and we don't want:

```
curl "http://localhost.com/dir/"
```

And then it's complaining it can't find "localhost.com" I have tried specifying the URL with the "--url" parameter but still see the same result.

Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Comment: Try putting there a port, like `http://localhost:80/dir`.

Comment: Just tried it. It still changes the host to "localhost.com:80". Very strange.

Comment: No hints arise if you try curl with `--verbose` or `--trace` options?